# Replace directive definition in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I use library AngularUI Bootstrap. And i want create a new custom directive "datepicker", but this directive defined in AngularUI Bootstrap.

Question:

- I can remove directive from any module?
- I can replace directive from any module?

Thank.

Comment: You don't have to use the same name.  Call your myDatepicker

Comment: Agree with @Malkus, just name it differently

Answer (score 2):

On the [UI Bootstrap site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) there's a button "Create a Build". You can leave out Datepicker so there's no name collision and use your own.